# wait list implementation in semaphore.c

Tags: c, list, linux-kernel, semaphore

this is the semaphore structure in semaphore.h

```
16 struct semaphore {
17         raw_spinlock_t          lock;
18         unsigned int            count;
19         struct list_head        wait_list;
20 };
```

and this is the wait queue structure in semaphore.c.

```
193 struct semaphore_waiter {
194         struct list_head list;
195         struct task_struct *task;
196         int up;
197 };
```

inside a function the following 3 statements are there.

```
207         struct task_struct *task = current;
208         struct semaphore_waiter waiter;
209 
210         list_add_tail(&waiter.list, &sem->wait_list);
```

I know that `list_add_tail` will add `waiter.list` to the tail of `sem->wait_list`. What I don't understand is, the resulting structure. Since `waiter.list` belongs to `semaphore_waiter` and `sem->wait_list` belongs to `struct semaphore`, will the resulting list be of type `struct semaphore` or `struct semaphore_waiter`?

Comment: so sorry ..yes it is regarding the linux kernel.

Answer (score 2):

[`list_add_tail`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-list-add-tail.html):

```
void list_add_tail(struct list_head * new,
                   struct list_head * head);
```

adds `new` to the beginning of the list pointed by `head`.

Note that most all lists in the kernel keep the `next`/`prev` pointers as a `list_head` structure, which is *part of the structure for the data in the list itself*.

So when you're iterating over a list (e.g. `p = p->next`), the `next` pointers will point *not* to the beginning of the data (here `struct semaphore_waiter`), but *rather* to the `list` member *of that structure*.

To get a pointer to the data contained in the list, you use the [`container_of`](http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html) macro. This returns a pointer to the structure which contains the `list`.

So, say you have a `struct semaphore *sem`, and for simplicity, we'll assume it has one `semaphore_waiter` in the list.  We can get a pointer to that waiter like:

```
struct semaphore *sem = <something>;
struct list_head *first;
struct semaphore_waiter *waiter;

// This is a pointer to the 'list' member of the first
// semaphore_waiter in the list
first = sem->wait_list.next;

// Now we "back out" from the list member to the
// (containing) semaphore_waiter itself
waiter = container_of(first, struct semaphore_waiter, list);
```

Comment: Does it mean that the head node will of type semaphore and the new node will be of type semaphore waiter.

Comment: @tunu Yes, I think it's safe to say that. (Although they're both actually just `struct list_head*`.)  The head of the list usually isn't an actual "item" of interest in the list.